# Sort a set of variables based on frequency from a Perl RegEx

Tags: regex, perl, sorting, arraylist, lua

I am attempting to use a table or array to list and sort items
this following sequence of letters, or items, by what is 'eaten'
first (in the captured perl RegEx) These four lists are the exact same
items, just entered in a different order, in succession.

Input items: these letters represent an action or an input into the
client.

> a b c d
>
> b c d a
>
> c d b a
>
> d a b c

perl regex:

```
^(\w+) eats (a|an) (\w+)\.$
```

So matches[4] will be the item captured.

This will trigger RegEx will fire in the client with 'each' set of
letters (a, b, c, d) Entered, separately. So four sets of a, b, c, d that
will be input in succession but on a rotating order basis. The above
RegEx will in fire 16x (once for each letter.) I need to be able to
sort it so, if (a) is eaten first every time, then that will have
priority at the top going down. But it might not always be (a), it
could be any of the letters that hold priority.

I need this priority list to be displayed to a Geyser such as

```
PrioList= Geyser.MiniConsole:new({
  name="PrioList",
  x="70%", y="50%",
  width="30%", height="50%",
})
```

I then need to be able to set each letter to a different priority list
or variable. Because each separate letter will indicate a different
action needed to be taken, so I will need to say

```
if (a == highestpriority) then 
do action / function()
end
```

I am unsure of how to write the 'for' statement that will be able to
sort and list these items based off the 4 groups of letters. I figure
the list will have to be saved and reset, after each sequence then
somehow entered into a table or array, and compared to each other for
the highest priority. But this seriously beyond what I know how to
script, but I would definitely love to learn this.

Comment: Can two or more letters share the same priority, i.e., all having the same frequency?

Comment: You are showing fragments of Lua code, but your question is tagged with Perl. Is that a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correctly understanding you, one option is to use a 1) hash to tally the frequency of the first letter entered, and 2) dispatch table to associate each letter with a subroutine:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw/shuffle/;

my %seen;
my %dispatchTable = (
    a => \&a_priority,
    b => \&b_priority,
    c => \&c_priority,
    d => \&d_priority
);

for my $i ( 1 .. 4 ) {
    my @chars = shuffle qw/a b c d/;
    print "Round $i: @chars\n";
    $seen{ $chars[0] }++;
}

my $priority = ( sort { $seen{$b} <=> $seen{$a} } keys %seen )[0];
print "Priority: $priority\n";

$dispatchTable{$priority}->();

sub a_priority {
    print "a priority sub called\n";
}

sub b_priority {
    print "b priority sub called\n";
}

sub c_priority {
    print "c priority sub called\n";
}

sub d_priority {
    print "d priority sub called\n";
}
```

Sample run output:

```
Round 1: d c a b
Round 2: b a d c
Round 3: d b a c
Round 4: c d a b
Priority: d
d priority sub called
```

You said, *"I need to be able to sort it so, if (a) is eaten first every time..."*  The above attempts to select the item with the highest frequency--not the item that was first all four times.

You'll need to decide what to do in cases where more than one letter shares the same frequency, but perhaps this will help provide some direction.